# How to show a dialog on a navigation view item select?

Tags: c#, navigationview, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am using [AvaloniaUI](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia) with [FluentAvalonia](https://github.com/amwx/FluentAvalonia) and i have an "About" [item](https://amwx.github.io/FluentAvaloniaDocs/pages/Controls/NavigationViewItem) in the [NavigationView](https://amwx.github.io/FluentAvaloniaDocs/pages/Controls/NavigationView) and i don't have that much to show, so making a separate page is too much and i want to show a small dialog, how can i achieve this?

I tried showing the dialog and switching back to the last view but i there is some data to show and it flickers and it doesn't seem like a great solution, more like a bad workaround...

Comment: Please show us what you tried and if you can please clarify your objective.  It's hard to tell what you are trying to do because you use the word "Dialog" which is exclusively a window but then mention showing it in the NavigationView.